# How to group module imports common across all modules in project?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, dry, python-import

I have a couple of `import` statements which I want to use in *every* module in my project:

```
import logging
if DEBUG:
    import ipdb
    from pprint import pprint
```

I don't want to paste the exact same code in 20 modules so I tried to group the `import` statements in a single module, `auxilliary_modules.py`. But when I put `import auxilliary_modules` in my modules, `logging`, `ipdb` and `pprint` don't seem to be imported:

> NameError: name 'logging' is not defined

Is there a way to follow the DRY principle here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you would need to do:

```
from auxilliary_modules import *
```

That would import all the attributes in the auxilliary_modules module into the local namespace.

Otherwise you would need do do this:

```
import auxilliary_modules
```

and instead of referencing "logging" (for example), reference:

```
auxilliary_modules.logging
```

Comment: "star imports" should NEVER be used in production code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't see why not. I'm just importing modules I would have imported in each module anyway.

Comment: @NewWorld: with star imports you don't have a clear an explicit control over which names are created in your module's namespace, and _from experience_ it can break your code in various unexpected ways (I won't list them here but believe me I've seen quite a few cases over the years).  As boring as explicit imports are, the gain in maintainability / robustness really outweight the few minutes they take initially. Been here, done that, still have the tee-shirt...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I suppose then I will do `import auxilliary_modules as G` (G for globals) so I don't have to type much and call things like `G.ipdb.set_trace()`. Is this good? Thanks for the advice

Comment: It's at least much more maintainable. I would not personnally allow it in my team except eventually  for a couple utility functions / wrappers because I don't want the overhead to have to lookup `auxilliary_modules.py` to find out that, say, `G.datetime` is really the stdlib's `datetime` package, but that's another question.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That overhead is less than importing the same 10 modules in every module of your project, no? That doesn't scale well. So when you need to add another module that should be imported in every project-module, is that less overhead than looking into `auxilliary_modules.py`?

Comment: @NewWorld I have yet to see a project where _each and every module_ depends on the _very same_ 10 modules and even less where I'd have to add a 11th module to that list... looks like a possible design smell to me. But well, I know nothing of your project and code base so I might just be plain wrong and you doing the RightThing.